# Java Swing Assigning a variable to a URL

Tags: java, xml, swing, netbeans, jar

Hello I'm developing a swing chat application where the chat history is being stored in an xml file.
I am able to fetch the xml file and display it in a table when done in the NetBeans project

But when converted to a jar file I am unable to use the xml file.
I've tried various things such as the getClass().getResource() method but it retrieves a URL rather than a string and if converted to a string using toString() method it cant be used as a valid path in order to parse the xml file.

Below is the code-->

ServerFrame.java

```
     public class ServerFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public String historyFile;
        public HistoryFrame historyFrame;
        public History hist;  }

        public ServerFrame() {
           historyFile=this.getClass().getResource("History.xml").toString();}


 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

            hist = new History(historyFile);               
            historyFrame = new HistoryFrame(hist);
            historyFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            historyFrame.setLocation(this.getLocation());
            historyFrame.setVisible(true);          
    }
```

History.java

```
public class History {

    public String filePath;

    public History(String filePath){

        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public void addMessage(Message msg, String time){

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filePath);

            Node data = doc.getFirstChild();

            Element message = doc.createElement("message");
            Element _sender = doc.createElement("sender"); _sender.setTextContent(msg.sender);
            Element _content = doc.createElement("content"); _content.setTextContent(msg.content);
            Element _recipient = doc.createElement("recipient"); _recipient.setTextContent(msg.recipient);
            Element _time = doc.createElement("time"); _time.setTextContent(time);

            message.appendChild(_sender); message.appendChild(_content); message.appendChild(_recipient); message.appendChild(_time);
            data.appendChild(message);

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filePath));
            transformer.transform(source, result);

       } 
           catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Exceptionmodify xml");
       }
    }

    public void FillTable(HistoryFrame frame){

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) frame.jTable1.getModel();

        try{
            File fXmlFile = new File(filePath);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("message");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{getTagValue("sender", eElement), getTagValue("content", eElement), getTagValue("recipient", eElement), getTagValue("time", eElement)});
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Filling Exception");
        }
    }
```

I have put the xml file in the src folder of Project directory.The problem seems to be in the docBuilder.parse() since everytime an exception is being generated in the function and it accepts only strings not urls since the system path of the file is different from javapath of the file.

I just need someway to access the xml file within the jar during execution. By access I mean just right filepath of xml file in the jar file and no need of file content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filePath));
```

As you already seem to know, a URL is not a file path, and you can’t treat it as one.  You simply cannot do `new File(filePath)` and expect it to work, ever.  The string you’re storing in `filePath` is not a file path at all, it’s a URL.

But you have a more fundamental problem:  A resource is read-only.  You can’t write to it, period.  All Java applications are deployed in .jar or .war files, and even if you can access the original archive (and there’s no guarantee you can), you may not have permission to write it (especially in Windows, where it’s likely to be locked), and even if you can write it, the application won’t see the changes.

In short, you should not try to write to a resource.

Instead, treat your resource as a default set of values, and choose a reliable location, such as a temporary file or a file in the user’s home directory, to write the new data:

```
File resultFile = File.createTempFile("history", ".xml");
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(resultFile);
```

A side note:  *Always* expose the stack trace of a caught exception, either with a logging statement, exception chaining, or at the very least, a call to printStackTrace().  Also, do not catch java.lang.Exception;  you should not suppress programmer errors like NullPointerException, IndexOutOfBoundsException, IllegalArgumentException, and so on.  Instead, catch only the exceptions you’re required to catch:

```
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | TransformerException ex) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the info never knew that resources within jar file cant be written. So what you are saying is create a seperate file outside and jar file  and access it right? Now if I do that when converting this jar file to an .exe file will it still be able to access that seperate file?Will the exe file be able to access that xml file?

Comment: Yes, .exe files should have the same permissions as a Java program run from a .jar or from an IDE.  Note that temporary files are not guaranteed to exist beyond the lifetime of your program, so if you need them to persist across runs, you should place them in a descendant of the user’s home directory;  exactly which directory is appropriate depends on the operating system.

Comment: Right got it now

Answer (score 0):

When running from an IDE you will not actually create a jar file and therefore you can get a resource from the directory structure. When packaging the application you will create jar file and resources are suddenly relative to a zip file. Reading from such a resource is possible but writing should not be done as it would change your package.

what you might need is to configure a specific location outside your jar location where you retrieve and write your xml file.

Comment: If I do that will I still be able to access that xml file when the jar file is converted to an executable .exe file? If not, what do you suggest?

Comment: Normally I would not recommend making an exe from a jar file. That limits it to Windows and jar is runnable everywhere. But apart from that yes why not? As long as you make it configurable in your application you can always read files from outside your jar file...

Comment: So the xml file can be accessed by the converted exe  file  as long as it can be accessed by the original jar file? What I mean is conversion of jar to exe dosent change the way the xml file is accessed right? I just wanna make sure conversion to exe does not impact the access of the xml file.